# No sound on Virtualbox Ubuntu with Mac OS X host

Tags: virtualbox

I've recently downloaded Ubuntu via Virtualbox on my macbook. The installation process was a charm and also I downloaded Virtualbox's extension pack. However, there is no audio whatsoever on the OS. I've tried everything on the web and still couldn't fix the problem.

I'm using Virtualbox 5.1.2 and and latest desktop version of Ubuntu.

This is the Audio menu on my Virtualbox:

[image]

I've tried all audio controllers and drivers. None of them work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is an Ubuntu problem.
Since virtual box 5.0.26+ there has been problems regarding sound on an OSX host no matter the guest os.
More info:  https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15611

U could downgrade to .26 (be sure to fix the right version of the extention-pack too) or hope for an update where its fixed; even the latest test-builds don't work yet.

Edit: newest version VirtualBox 5.1.4 seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the Multimedia > PulseAudio Volume Control options in the whisker window?
I solved the problem I had by adjusting the audio output options under the  Playback, Output Devices and Configuration tabs.  Hope this helps.